# Scala: Proper way to get name of class for an object?

Tags: scala, reflection

I have a class that contains a main method, and I wish to start a new process that runs this class.

But when I try to use Scala to get the name of this class, it gives me the wrong name. For example:

```
object Test {
  def main(args: Array[String]) = { 
    println(Test.getClass.getCanonicalName)
  }
}
```

Then:

```
roei@roei-main:~/Java$ scalac Test.scala 
roei@roei-main:~/Java$ scala Test
Test$
roei@roei-main:~/Java$ javap Test*.class
Compiled from "Test.scala"
public final class Test {
  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
}
Compiled from "Test.scala"
public final class Test$ {
  public static final Test$ MODULE$;
  public static {};
  public void main(java.lang.String[]);
}
```

`Test.getClass.getCanonicalName` gives me `Test$`, **not** `Test`. But the static main method is inside of a class named `Test`, whereas `Test$` contains a non-static main. Obviously I can do the workaround of just deleting the `$` at the end, but I'm looking for a more satisfying/reliable solution.

Comment: Test is not a class, it is an object. Inside that object, there is Test$, which is the class for your object Test.

Comment: @SebastianCelestino Thanks. But for my purposes, I need "Test", not "Test$". Is there a better way of doing this than just deleting the dollar sign at the end of the string?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A possible solution would be using `ClassTag` of `scala.reflect` ([see API](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/reflect/ClassTag.html)). I mean something like the following:

```
import scala.reflect.ClassTag
import scala.reflect.classTag

class Test

object Test {
  def main(args: Array[String]) = { 
    println(Test.getClass.getCanonicalName)
    println(classTag[Test].runtimeClass.getCanonicalName)
  }
}
```

it will print:

```
Test$  
Test
```